# VBA Code to Populate Balance Sheet from Trial Balance Data

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon folks,

I've been a long time reader but first time poster. I am doing a project that requires me to take trial balance data in Excel and format that data into a "balance sheet".

Basically I have the trial balance data in one worksheet ("Data") and the balance sheet template in another sheet ("Balance Sheet")

I need to populate the balance sheet from the ("Data") sheet to the ("Balance Sheet"). I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this

I have a first macro that I recorded that formats the trial balance data by account number and a second macro that sums together each group of accounts (ex. all cash accounts on are summed together on one line in the balance sheet).

But I am having trouble making this code robust and flexible, currently it is hard coded to the values in the balance sheet. How can I make this code flexible so that it populates correctly, (for example, if I added another "cash" account to the cash group, it would add that amount to the "cash" line in the balance sheet)

Here is the file if needed to look into it. Not a whole lot of code so any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=22382427361802516291

[http://imgur.com/a/bYjUp](https://imgur.com/a/bYjUp)

Comment: Could you post an example of your workbook? (file or picture) Including the code you have so far would help too

Comment: yep i just added a link to my project file which contains the workbook

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't downloaded your project yet but it seems that what you need to do is create an array for each type of account. For simplicity, let's say you just have arrCash and arrLiability.  You would then fill the arrays with each known gl code.or another way would be to keep a list of gl codes on a seperate spreadsheet. Now comes the fun part. You would loop through your excel spreadsheet and compare each code to the elements in your arrays. If the comparison equals true then add that amount to a one of your variables. If the comparison equals false then create a routine that redims the array the gl code needs to be added to then adds that gl code to the array. Or adding to that seperate spreadsheet.  After adding the new gl code to the array you would need to add that amount to it's corresponding variable. After all calculations are completed, then you would update your balance sheet with the amoubts in the variables. Easy enough, right?

Comment: Michael, thanks for your input. dont have to much exposure to arrays. But I understand the logic. Do you think it would be possible to use an if statement to assign gl codes to each of the accounts. then use sum + vlookup to populate the balance sheet? any other tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following function accepts a comma delimited list of values (the value from column a in Data sheet) and will sum all rows in the data sheet that match the provided values.

eg: ?getSum("10300-000,10303-000") = 433094.74

```
Public Function getSum(ByVal Search As String) As Double
Dim Data As Worksheet: Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Dim List() As String: List = Split(Search, ",")
Dim ListSize As Integer: ListSize = UBound(List)
Dim Values() As Variant
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim Match As Integer
Dim Matched As Boolean

Dim Result As Double: Result = 0

Rows = Data.Range("A" & Data.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Values = Data.Range("A1", "C" & Rows).Value2

Row = 1

Do
    Matched = False
    For Match = 0 To ListSize
        If Values(Row, 1) = List(Match) Then
            Matched = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Match

    If Matched = True Then
        Result = Result + CDbl(Values(Row, 3))
    End If

    If Row >= Rows Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Row = Row + 1
    End If
Loop

getSum = Result

End Function
```

Updated to allow range of accounts instead of list

```
Public Function getSum2(ByVal sFirst As String, ByVal sLast As String) As Double
Dim Data As Worksheet: Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Dim Values() As Variant
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim First As Long: First = CLng(Left(sFirst, 5))
Dim Test As Long
Dim Last As Long: Last = CLng(Left(sLast, 5))
Dim Result As Double: Result = 0

Rows = Data.Range("A" & Data.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Values = Data.Range("A1", "C" & Rows).Value2

Row = 1

Do
    Test = CLng(Left(Values(Row, 1), 5))

    If Test >= First And Test <= Last Then
        Result = Result + CDbl(Values(Row, 3))
    End If

    If Row >= Rows Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Row = Row + 1
    End If
Loop

getSum2 = Result

End Function
```

Comment: Nick Thanks very much, is there a way to make it so that I can change the code for the user defined function so that when I enter getSum("10300-000,10925-000") it will sum ALL of the account numbers between these two account numbers and not just the ones specified in the function? Thanks again!

Comment: If it's always 5 digits, a hyphen and 3 zeros then it would be fairly simple yes. Instead of a single delimited parameter, have two then take the left five characters and convert them to integers, you can then replace the for loop with a single if statement 'if cint(left(values(row,1),5) > ... or cint(...) < .... Then